# Cross filtering with multiple checkbox categories in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, checkbox

I would like to filter data in a d3 map using two different checkbox categories, one for "tenant" and one for "broker".  I can filter successfully by either category by itself, but the issue I'm having is getting both filters to work together.  For example, if I re-check a box in one category it will bring back all the data for that category, regardless of what is checked/unchecked in the other category. I'd like to filter data on multiple categories at once.  Here's my code:

```
//"Tenant" checkboxes
<div class="Regus" style="margin-right:30px; margin- 
    top:13px">Regus
    <input class ='tenantcheck' type="checkbox" 
    id="RegusCheckbox"  checked/>
    <label  for="RegusCheckbox"></label>
</div>

<div class="Spaces" style="margin-right:30px; margin-top:13px">Spaces
    <input class ='tenantcheck' type="checkbox" id="SpacesCheckbox"  checked/>
    <label  for="SpacesCheckbox"></label>
</div>


//"Broker" checkboxes
<label class="container" >CBRE
    <input class ='agencyBrokerCheck' type="checkbox" id="CBRECheckbox" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label class="container" >Colliers
    <input class ='agencyBrokerCheck' type="checkbox" 
    id="ColliersCheckbox" checked >
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

//Filter by "Tenant"
d3.selectAll("#RegusCheckbox").on("change", function() {
            var type = "Regus"
            display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
            d3.selectAll(".features")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Tenant === type; })
            .attr("display", display);
            });

d3.selectAll("#SpacesCheckbox").on("change", function() {
            var type = "Spaces"
            display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
            d3.selectAll(".features")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Tenant === type; })
            .attr("display", display);
            });

//And, filter by "Broker"
d3.selectAll("#CBRECheckbox").on("change", function() {
            var type = "CBRE"
            display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
            d3.selectAll(".features")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Agency_Bro === type; })
            .attr("display", display);
            });
d3.selectAll("#ColliersCheckbox").on("change", function() {
            var type = "Colliers International"
            display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
            d3.selectAll(".features")
            .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Agency_Bro === type; })
            .attr("display", display);
            });
```

Is there a way to keep this general logic while allowing d3 to filter by both these categories at once?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: save the result of the filter check in the `d.properties`, then set display based on these 2 boolean values: `.attr("display", d => d.a && d.b ? "inline: "none")`

Comment: This sort of makes sense, but how are you thinking I save the result of the filter check?  For each category, there will be multiple checkboxes (as shown above).

Comment: Could I add a line after .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Tenant === type; }) d => d.a  ?  I'm assuming that way d.a would continually be updated based on which checkbox is added.. but if I'm missing something here.. let me know.  Thanks so much.

Comment: create 2 objects with properties equal to all the types possible with boolean values. Update the boolean values when boxes are checked. Then `d3.selectAll(".features").attr("display", d => tenant[d.properties.Tenant] || agency[d.properties.Agency_Bro] ? "inline: "none")`

Comment: rio - Ok, thanks.  I sort of understand the logic.  What if I iterate over an object of all tenant names, and push into an array?  When the boxes are checked, it will update the object and the tenant names pushed into the array.  Then in the .filter function, I could use something to the effect of 'if d.properties.Tenant 'in' the array ', then filter..?

Comment: searching for an element in a list is much slower then accessing a property of an object

Comment: I've got this working now.  Thank you.  Basically, I made an object with every tenant name, and then matched properties to see if it's name was in the object array.  So, sort of what you described.